# Как правильно работать с рекурсивной структурой

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Есть структура которая передается в функцию, структура имеет вид

```golang
type T struct {
    ID int
    L  *T
    R  *T
}
```

Собственно, `L` и `R` позволяет перемещаться по структуре влево или вправо, структура может быть передана в любой позиции, т.е. в левую сторону могут быть данные а может и `nil`, как корректно работать с такой структурой?
Нужно проходить её по циклу, но как это сделать "красиво" я что-то не могу придумать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```golang
type T struct {
    ID int
    L  *T
    R  *T
}

func (t *T) leftSum() (sum int) {
    for t := t; t != nil; t = t.L {
        sum += t.ID
    }

    return sum
}
```

Пример целиком: https://play.golang.org/p/xjKB1z2ATt7.

Comment: И потом отдельно делать для R?

Comment: Тут уж вам решать, в зависимости от алгоритма и задачи.